# How can I use the JsonObject class?

Tags: c#, .net, json, windows-phone-7

I am building on Windows Phone 7. I noticed in the documentation I can:

```
JsonObject user = (JsonObject)JsonObject.Load(responseStream);
bool isMember = user["IsMember"];
string name = user["Name"];
int age = user["Age"];
```

How can I import the JsonObject class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `using System.Json;` to the top of your file.

**Edit**
It seems that Windows Phone 7 doesn't support the `System.Json` namespace so you cannot do it this way. After a cursory search, it seems you have to use the `DataContractJsonSerializer` class as shown in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/hh237494) MSDN video/source code.

You may also want to consider using [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) which appears to be much more efficient than the `DataContractJsonSerializer`.

Comment: This class does not exist on Windows Phone 7.

Comment: @Chris R: I'm not sure how Sheehan got it to work then, but try [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/bd7d6f01-66b2-496d-a1f2-285489e3177a?lc=1033) link for info.

Answer (score 4):

I think this library is now deprecated in favour of Json.NET. JsonObject is now a JObject and requires Json.NET library.

[Documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm)