# How can I parse the following JSON for Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, .net, json, windows-phone-7, arrays

I have a JSON result that has an array of messages:

```
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "message": {
        "for_user_login": null,
        "message_type": "normal",
        "twitter_in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
        "avatar_url": "http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/82661470/marshallwithhatbig_normal.jpg",
        "created_at": "2010-11-16T18:50:33Z",
        "body": "Watch the Web 2.0 Summit Live on Video, for Free: http://me.lt/24mH (tickets cost $Ks, content is good)",
        "filtered": false,
        "future": false,
        "in_reply_to_user_login": null,
        "twitter_user_id": 818340,
        "updated_at": "2010-11-16T18:50:33Z",
        "user_login": "marshallk",
        "group_ids": null,
        "stock_ids": "8030",
        "twitter_created_at": "2010-11-16T18:50:27Z",
        "id": 2124647,
        "mention_ids": null,
        "twitter_in_reply_to_user_id": null,
        "platform_user_login": null,
        "twitter_status_id": 4607245530697728,
        "user_id": null,
        "for_user_id": null,
        "recommended": false,
        "private_relations": false,
        "investor_relations": false,
        "forex": false,
        "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
        "stock_symbols": "KS",
        "twitter_in_reply_to_status_id": null,
        "twitter_source": "<a href=\"http://rockmelt.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">RockMelt</a>",
        "chart": false,
        "in_reply_to_message_id": null,
        "message_source": "twitter"
      }
    }
}
```

here is my code:

```
void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(e.Result)))
            {
                JsonObject messages = (JsonObject)JsonObject.Load(stream);
                MessageBox.Show(messages.ToString(), "Data Passed", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure how I can pull out the JSON object that is nested inside the root JSON object?

I have also tried with no luck:

```
 JsonObject jsonString = (JsonObject)JsonObject.Parse(e.Result);
            JsonArray messages = (JsonArray)jsonString["messages"]["message"];

            foreach (JsonObject message in messages)
            {
                foreach (string body in message.Keys)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(body);
                    Debug.WriteLine(message[body]);
                }
            }
```

Comment: With regards to the windows-phone-7 tag, what namespace/DLL is the JsonObject coming from? I see you also asked this here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197646/how-can-i-use-the-jsonobject-class) but it still doesn't make sense for wp7 without a third party library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var list = messages["messages"];
```

I would maybe rename your `messages` variable to `data` to be more descriptive.

P.S. I've never seen my last name as a first name!

Comment: I don't think I still understand. What will var list contain? How can I pull out the 'message' block from 'messages'? Ultimately I want to populate a listbox

Comment: It will contain a JsonArray which inherits from IEnumerable<JsonValue> so you can loop over it

Comment: would you be able to provide me a little code snippet that is looping over the JsonArray, showing how to pull out the message block?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you directly use `JsonObject.Parse(e.Result)`?

You do not need to use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` or `MemoryStream`.

And then you can get data from inside the JSON object as stated by @John.

Comment: I am still not familiar how to get the data inside the json object as stated by @John. Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 1):

use http://json2csharp.com/ to get csharp object and used serialize/deserialize JSON data.